# gdal_translate translation from jp2 to geotiff scales the values for no reason

Tags: gdal-translate

I have download a sentinel-2 image and I am using gdal_translate to convert it from jp2 to geotiff using this python command:

```
kwargs_gdal = {'format': 'GTiff',
                   'xRes': xRes,
                   'yRes': yRes,
                   'outputType': outputType}
gdal.Translate(new_band_name, imageBand, **kwargs_gdal)
```

where `outputType=gdal.GDT_UInt16`.
I noticed (in QGIS) that my initial jp2 image has range 0-13035 and when I convert it in python I open it in qgis again and has pixel range 0-16560.
Also, I did the translation in qgis using this command:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff T37TEH_20231014T080901_B08_10m.jp2 OUTPUT.tif
```

and again the output image has pixel values rangin from 0-16560, which is the same as output of gdal in python.
I want preserve the values of the input image, and this can be done by not using -scale parameter. I also have used -scale parameter as:
-scale 0 13035 0 13035 but still the output has 0-16560 range pixel values.

**I have not no_data values in my initial image.

Why is this still happening?

Comment: Did you check the data ranges with QGIS? Does it probably show this metadata `STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES` for the jp2 or both? `-scale 0 13035 0 13035` does not cip the data, it just defines two points for linear interpolation. That is also documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-scale. So with these values -scale does nothing.